# Anchor tags are not working in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

My anchor tags for all my `ul` elements are not working, meaning when I hover over them on the actual site they don't click and nothing happens. The last element works ("Contact") but that's the only one that works. I also have other `a` tags on the website and they work except these on the `ul`.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="footer, address, phone, icons" />

    <title>Ask Uptown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pp.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Raleway|Signika|Signika+Negative" rel="stylesheet">
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="logo">
          <h3 class="logo-text">Uptown<span>Ask</span></h3>
        </div>

        <ul id="main-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Stuck? Ask a question!</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="hero">
        <h1>Start Asking now</h1>

        <div class="buttons">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-one">Ask Now!</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-two">Sign Up Now!</a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </header>
    <section>
      <div class="about">
        <h1>How Uptown Ask works?</h1>
        <p class="paragraph-about">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="section">
        <div class="card-pic">
          <h4>Ask A Question</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-pic-two">
          <h4>Get An Answer</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-pic-three">
          <h4>Use The Answer</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


            <footer class="footer-distributed">

                <div class="footer-left">

                    <h3>Uptown<span>Ask</span></h3>

                    <p class="footer-links">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                        ·
                        <a href="#">Blog</a>
                        ·
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                        ·
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </p>

                    <p class="footer-company-name">Ask Uptown &copy; 2017</p>
                </div>

                <div class="footer-center">

                    <div class="adress-sec">
                        <p class="p-adress">Address: Tripoli Street, Algeria Road, Mirdif Area - Dubai, United Arab Emirtes</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="phone-sec">
                        <p>Phone: 04 251 5001</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="email-sec">
                        <p class="p-email"><a href="mailto:rayanza3eem1234@gmail.com">Email: Uptownschool@gmail.com</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="footer-right">

                    <p class="footer-company-about">
                        <span>About the company</span>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectateur adispicing elit. Fusce euismod convallis velit, eu auctor lacus vehicula sit amet.
                    </p>

                    <div class="icons">

                        <a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" class="twitter" ></a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" class="facebook" ></a>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="insta.png" alt="Instagram" class="instagram" ></a>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </footer>

  </body>
</html>
code here
```

And my CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(uptown.jpg);
  height: 65vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


.logo img{
  width: 190px;
  height: 65px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
}

.row{
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.hero{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 210px;
  margin-left: 55px;
}

.buttons{
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 490px;
}

.btn{
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.buttons a:hover{
  background-color: #cdc9c9;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.about{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  color: #F4F7F8;
}
.about h1{
  color: black;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.paragraph-about{
  color:black;
  font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #F4F7F8;
}


.card-pic{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 870px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card-pic h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-pic p{
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}


.card-pic-two{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 485px;
  top: 870px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.card-pic-two h4{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-pic-two p{
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.card-pic-three{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 900px;
  top: 870px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.card-pic-three h4{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-pic-three p{
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

#main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
}

#main-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#main-nav li:hover a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #292c2f;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;

    padding: 55px 50px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 40%;
}

/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  #5383d3;
}

/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Footer Center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #5383d3;
    text-decoration: none;;
}


/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 20%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* If you don't want the footer to be responsive, remove these media queries */

@media (max-width: 880px) {

    .footer-distributed{
        font: bold 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-center,
    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
    }

}

.twitter{
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}


.facebook{
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}

.instagram {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.icons{
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.adress{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.email{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.phone{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.adress-sec{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.phone-sec{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo-text{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 12px;
    float: left;
}

.logo-text span{
  color: #5383d3;
}
```

if I remove the `float: right` command on the main-nav, it works but then it's not on the right place.

Comment: Might be helpful to reproduce the issue in a code snippet sharing side like CodePen.io and then share a link to it here, that way others can get started right in on investigating your issue.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwexZe @Mattygabe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `hero` has a  position of `absolute` and the `h1` tag inside has a `maring-top` of 210px. This makes the hero div to overlay the buttons therefore making them un-clickable.

A tip is to get to know your browser's devtools, it is a really powerful debugging tool.

Since hero is a absolute element,use the [css property top](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp) Instead of using `margin-top`. This will not influence with the other elements. Have a look in your developer console:

```
.hero{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 210px;
}

h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

with margin
[image]
With top
[image]

Comment: when you go under, you see that there is a space between the footer and the last section, why is that happening? can you provide me with a solution?

Comment: Instead of absolute positioning the .card-pic's make them position: relative. and add display: inline-block. Also remove left and top. You should do that the most places you can, this way you will have reliable elements and it will be more responsive.

Comment: still has the space, any other solution? Thanks for the other solutions though helped a lot!!!!

Comment: @RayanSaleh It works for me :) I think you need to look at relative lengths

Answer (score 0):

i believe your problem starts in this part in css file:

```
.hero{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

you defined hero div to cover over the li's so you cant hover over them anymore.whenever you put the mouse over them its on the .hero div and not emitting the hover event needed for CSS.

my advice is whenever you are stuck like this right click and start using "inspect element". next time you will see it on your own.

you can remove the "position:absolute" and it will work then.